# Swing JTree: It seems to be impossible to properly send treeStructureUpdated events to model listeners

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTree displaying my own TreeModel. The TreeModel is loaded "on demand" from a database (somewhat ugly since partially done on the EDT, but thats not my issue here). There is a menu which will allow the user to select a filter to be applied to the tree.

When changing the filter, nodes may be hidden by the TreeModel or new nodes may be revealed. This is where my problem lies - I see no reasonable way of generating the appropiate treeStructureChanged events from the model, since I have no idea which nodes really have changed. There seems to be no simple way of telling the listeners that the entire model is now (potentially) different.

Is there a simple way of telling all TreeModelListeners that the entire model has been changed? (Of course I want to retain selection/expansion state as far as possible).

Comment: I don't know something about that 1) http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/jtree/ 2) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/implementsTreeModeltocreatetreemodel.htm 3) http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to signal that the entire tree structure has changed, send a [`TreeModelEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeModelEvent.html) for the tree's root to each listener. The [`GenealogyModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/GenealogyExampleProject/src/components/GenealogyModel.java) method `fireTreeStructureChanged()` is an example mentioned in [*How to Use Trees: Creating a Data Model*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data).

Comment: Simply sending an event for the root node refreshes the tree nicely, but also collapses the entire tree and removes the selection. I can work around that, but it leaves a bad taste.